# HTTP_USER_AGENT and navigator.userAgent not same, any idea?

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

I use Javascript in client, get `navigator.userAgent`, returns:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; HPNTDF; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

use C# `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`, returns:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
```

As you can see, its IE :(.

IE always do this, or just me?
How to get the same value?

**PS**, I tried this even in local IIS, same results

Comment: did you get an answer for this?

Comment: NO. It just different, in IE. No idea why, specially happen lots on reload (not first hit).

Answer (score 1):

The user agent string in Internet Explorer nine and higher will almost always differ, between the version send in the HTTP request and the one obtained via `navigator.userAgent`. This is because of the so called feature tokens in the string. The background for this is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

From the msdn-document:

> Earlier versions of Internet Explorer included feature tokens defined using the Pre-Platform and Post-Platform keys part of the user-agent string during the HTTP negotiation process. Over time, this lead to overly long user-agent strings, which in turn created problems for certain web servers. Problems usually appeared when user-agent strings were longer than 256 characters. As of Internet Explorer 9, the user-agent string no longer includes feature tokens during HTTP negotiation. Feature tokens are included in the value returned by the userAgent property of the navigator object. Applications that rely on the earlier behavior should be modified accordingly.

You must decide witch one you want to use in your application. There is no way to "synchronize" them. The one obtained via Javascript should contain more information...